# Parameter not initialzed in ASP.NET CORE 2.1 when it is in ASP.NET CORE 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been following an excellent course on pluralsight and amending the code to suit my own application.

The course used ASP.NET CORE 2.0 when creating the project. I've used 2.1 thinking there wouldn't be much difference.

However, I've come across a difference in the two versions.

•   Start New Project: testcore2.0

•   Select API and version ASP.NET Core 2.0, Click OK
The project is then up and running

•   Add a Helpers folder

•   Inside the Helpers folder, Add a class: TestHelper.cs

•   Add a string property to the TestHelper class

```
namespace TestCore20.Helpers
{
  public class TestHelper
  {
    public string TestString { get; set; } = "string";
  }
}
```

•   In ValuesController.cs, add the using clause using TestCore20.Helpers;

```
using TestCore20.Helpers;
```

•   In the Get method add the TestHelper as a parameter
In the Get method add a string variable that will receive the Teststring in the TestHelper and set a breakpoint on it.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get(TestHelper th)
{
  string testString = th.TestString;

  return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

If you then run the project, it stops at the breakpoint and you can check th and confirm it has been initiated.

This all works as expected.

However if we repeat the steps in new project and use ASP.NET CORE 2.1 the th class returns a null reference. It isn’t initialised.

How do I get the object to initialise in ASP.NET CORE 2.1?

Comment: Why don't you download the code from pluralsight and  check the differences between projects?

Comment: I've been looking at the code for weeks. I've been looking at the specific code related to this issue for nearly a day.

If you read my post, you'll see code differences aren't the issue.
My initial post gives steps on how to create a simple project. If you run the project using the two different ASP.NET CORE versions, you will be able to duplicate the issue.


I then ran the test that I mention in my query and found that the issue appears down to the different versions of ASP.NET CORE.

Comment: Then start a issue in GitHub to asp.net-core-mvc page.

Comment: Try by addind a `[FromQuery]` attribute. `public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromQuery] TestHelper th)`. By the way, it's a normal behavior to have a `null` if you don't pass any queryString in your request.

Comment: Sakuto: That has resolved the issue. Thank you very much.